# how to convert byte to hex string in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, string, byte

Hi i have a bytes and i want to convert it into string, can you help me?

the byte data is in the form of

```
b'@\x040\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00a\xd5\n'
```

I want it in the form of

```
'@\x040\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00a\xd5\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

use the decode function.

`b'@\x040\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00a\xd5\n'.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 11: invalid continuation byte


,it gives this error